# Conectarme a internet en Linux (Ubuntu) Servidor DNS BIND

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns, internet

Muy buenas, estoy haciendo unos ejercicios Servicios de Red, y en este caso es una actividad sobre DNS LINUX. En esta actividad tengo que trabajar con dos maquinas virtuales de Linux, una es un servidor y otra es un cliente. Aun no he configurado la maquina del cliente. Total en la maquina virtual estoy intenando insertar una ip dinamica en el archivo 01-network-manager-all.yaml del directorio /etc/netplan:

```
network:
 version: 2
 renderer: NetworkManager
 ethernets:
  enp0s3:
   dhcp: no
   addresses: [192.168.201.59/24]
   gateway4: 192.168.201.1
   nameservers:
    addresses: [192.168.201.59]
```

Como pueden ver debe estar congigurada de esa forma por la primera actividad del ejercicio. En el me dice que inserte una ip 192.168.201.50+x, la x por el numero de pc que tengo en clase que es el 9. Pero ahora la estoy intentando hacer en mi ordenador personal, asi que pongo la misma. Tengo alguna duda de que tenga que poner esa ip en mi ordenador pero la dejo así de momento.

Total, el servidor dns local como pueden ver va a ser nuestro Servidor: addresses: [192.168.201.59]. Siguiendo con la actividad debo editar el archivo named.conf.options de el directorio /etc/bind/, en el que están los forwaders, y le tengo que insertar estos dos:

```
forwaders {
   127.20.0.100; 8.8.8.8;
}
```

Luego hago un systemctl restart bind9, y obviamente anteriormente hice el netplan apply. Y aqui es donde la maquina virtual deberia conectarme a internet, pero no lo hace desde un principio. Al hacer un nslookup para probarlo: nslookup [www.google.es](http://www.google.es) no da ningún resultado, y no se que es lo que está pasando. Necesito obviamente que tenga internet para seguir haciendo el ejercicio para configurar las zonas directas e inversas para tener conectividad entre Servidor y Cliente. La maquina que tengo del cliente es una copia de la del Servidor así que esa la tengo que configurar de la misma forma que lel Servidor, solo que su dns será el servidor. Si me ha faltado alún dato o cualquier cosa diganmelo.

En mi archivo resolv.conf del directorio /etc/ siempre me pone el mismo nameserver: nameserver: 127.0.0.53, cuando deberia ser la que le proporcione por el addresses.

Comment: No se seguro, pero creo que el problema es que estás probando la ip de clase, cuando en tu casa debe de ser otro rango. Si no pones la puerta de enlace correcta y el mismo segmento de red, no funcionará sin hacer más cosas, así por ejemplol si tu red local es 192.168.1.x, por lo general, la puerta de enlace será 192.168.1.1 (la ip del router), pero al tratarse de una red virtual, no puedo saber las ips que usas ni la puerta de enlace.

Comment: Depende del virtualizador que usas. Aunque realmente no necesitas internet para levantar un DNS, ya que puede ser un DNS local.